# My discord bot has some sort of role error

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am trying to create a discord bot that speaks over people.
I can get it to join a call but when I mark a person to annoy it crashes and gives this error:

TypeError [INVALID_TYPE]: Supplied roles is not a Role, Snowflake or Array or Collection of Roles or Snowflakes.

```
  }
  if (command === "mark" && msg.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_CHANNELS"))
  {
        if (!msg.mentions.users.size) {
      return msg.reply('You need to tag a user in order to mark them!');
    }
    let markedUser = msg.mentions.members.first();
    let role = msg.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === "Donnies Target");
        markedUser.roles.add(role)

        return msg.channel.send(`${markedUser} has been marked!`);      
  }
  if (command === "unmark" && msg.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_CHANNELS"))
  {
      if(!args.length)
        return msg.channel.send(`Please tag a user!`);
        let unmarkUser = msg.mentions.members.first();
        let role = msg.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === "Donnies Target");
        unmarkUser.roles.remove(role)
      msg.channel.send(`${unmarkUser} has been unmarked`);
  }
```

Comment: Please include the relevant code in the question itself (Not in a link)

Comment: And please fix the formatting

Comment: should be fixed now

Comment: And what's the error you're getting?

Comment: TypeError [INVALID_TYPE]: Supplied roles is not a Role, Snowflake or Array or Collection of Roles or Snowflakes.

Comment: Had you try making sure that your ``Donnies Target`` role does exist and the bot is able to see it ? Try adding : ``console.log(role);`` and what does it output ?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
let role = msg.guild.roles.cache.get("ROLE_ID_HERE");
```

this should return a Role Object **(Make sure the role ID comes from the role with the name: `Donnies Target`)**